# How to disable input on unused Text Boxes once a certain number of boxes are used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A user is allowed to enter information in 5 input boxes.

I want the user to only be allowed to answer 3 questions from the form and as he answers the 3 questions of his choice the rest of the input text fields (boxes) in the form become disabled.

```
<html>    
<h1>Security Questions</h1>
<body>
<p>
Only Enter Answer 3 Security Questions.
</p>
<form action="/submitAnswer.php" method="POST">

<label>What City Was Your Mom Born In?</label><br>
<input type="text" id="secQuestion01" name="secQuestion01"><br>

<label>What Is Your Dream Car?</label><br>
<input type="text" id="secQuestion02" name="secQuestion02"><br>

<label>What Is Your Mother's Maidan Name?</label><br>
<input type="text" name="secQuestion03"><br>

<label>What's Your Dream Job?</label><br>
<input type="text" name="secQuestion04"><br>

<label>Name Your First Grade Teacher?</label><br>
<input type="text" name="secQuestion05"><label><br>

<label>Name Your First Pet?</label><br>
<input type="text" name="secQuestion01"><label><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `I am working on` I don't see any of your Javascript? Please edit your question to include it so we can see what the problem is

Comment: How would you know which ones to disable? You don't know what they want to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a `keypress` event listener to each of the `input`s and increment a global variable when new input is added in other `input`s. If the variable is equal to 3, disable all of the other `input`s. If you want to allow the user to delete their answer to one question and answer another question, you will need to add a `keydown` event listener to each of the inputs and if the event's `keyCode` is 8 (backspace) and the current input's value's length is 1, then enable all of the other `input`s.

```html
<html>  
<body>
<h1>Security Questions</h1>
<p>
Only Enter Answer 3 Security Questions.
</p>
<form action="/submitAnswer.php" method="POST" id="questionForm">

<label>What City Was Your Mom Born In?</label><br>
<input type="text" id="secQuestion01" name="secQuestion01"><br>

<label>What Is Your Dream Car?</label><br>
<input type="text" id="secQuestion02" name="secQuestion02"><br>

<label>What Is Your Mother's Maidan Name?</label><br>
<input type="text" name="secQuestion03"><br>

<label>What's Your Dream Job?</label><br>
<input type="text" name="secQuestion04"><br>

<label>Name Your First Grade Teacher?</label><br>
<input type="text" name="secQuestion05"><label><br>

<label>Name Your First Pet?</label><br>
<input type="text" name="secQuestion01"><label><br>
</form>
<script>
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#questionForm input');
var entered = [];
var numOfEntered = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
  entered[i] = false;
  inputs[i].addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
      if(!entered[i]){
        entered[i] = true;
        numOfEntered++;
        if(numOfEntered==3){
          for(let j = 0; j < entered.length; j++){
            if(!entered[j]){
              inputs[j].disabled = true;
            }
          }
        }
      }
  });
  inputs[i].addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==8&&this.value.length==1){
      entered[i] = false; 
      numOfEntered--;
      for(let z = 0; z < entered.length; z++){
        inputs[z].disabled = false;
      }
    }
  });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The following will accomplish what you need:

```js
$(function () {

  $('input').on('focusout', function () {
    
    var $inputs = $('input');
    
    var numAnswered = $inputs.filter(function () {
      return $(this).val() !== '';
    }).length;
    
    $.each($inputs, function () {
      if (numAnswered < 3) {
        $(this).prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
          $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        }
      }
    });
    
    
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>    
<body>
<h1>Security Questions</h1>
<p>
Only Enter Answer 3 Security Questions.
</p>
<form action="/submitAnswer.php" method="POST">

<label>What City Was Your Mom Born In?</label><br>
<input type="text" id="secQuestion01" name="secQuestion01"><br>

<label>What Is Your Dream Car?</label><br>
<input type="text" id="secQuestion02" name="secQuestion02"><br>

<label>What Is Your Mother's Maidan Name?</label><br>
<input type="text" name="secQuestion03"><br>

<label>What's Your Dream Job?</label><br>
<input type="text" name="secQuestion04"><br>

<label>Name Your First Grade Teacher?</label><br>
<input type="text" name="secQuestion05"><label><br>

<label>Name Your First Pet?</label><br>
<input type="text" name="secQuestion01"><label><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do not use the answer that @hev1 has provided as it does not function reliably. For example, if you type values in for three of the inputs, then delete a character from any of those three inputs, the other inputs are then enabled so you can continue to type in values for the additional controls.